# Way to Edit Properties in a List collection in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
    public class VerifyLicensorModel
    {
        public int TempId { get; set; } 
        public string Licensor { get; set; } 
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int LicensorId { get; set; }
        public int ActionId { get; set; }   
        public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my model and i am getting this list as a result of excel import and i am asking user to verify the data

So for each licensor users should select an action [ actionId ] and there is a reference based on action user selcted [ ReferenceId ] as well
So to pick ActionId and ReferenceId i am using a modal popup which allow user to select action and referenceID [ The process of deciding these 2 params is but complex include a lot of conditional checks and parallel selection of inputs , 
 Example First decide liceonsor is new or existing . If decision is existing find existing id , related addressses. Then decide use new address or replace existing address . If decision is to replace existing select the one to replace

Thats why planning tokeep its logic as a seprate one and return with result only ie 2 Ids actionid and referenceID]

On submission how can i set the values of these 2 properties 
My view i am planning like this

```
        @model  IList<ApplicationLab.Models.VerifyLicensorModel>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                      Licensor
                    </th>
                    <th>
                     Address
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Action
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Verify
                    </th>
                </tr>
              @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) 
              {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].TempId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].LicensorId)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Licensor)                                
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => Model[i].Address)
                        </td>
                        <td>                                  
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].ActionId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].ReferenceId)                             
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a >Verify</a> // onclick plannig to show popup
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10" style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "LicenseImport", "Import", new { @id = @ViewBag.EditionId }, new { @class = "btn btn-link" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

So is my approach is correct ? if so how can i set the selected row property ? 
Or is any better approach or examples to suggest to implement the same?

Comment: Not related but please don't use `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].TempId)` - (capital M) - it can cause errors in some circumstances - use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].TempId)`

Comment: Why not just use dropdownlists for those properties instead of a popup to make the changes?

Comment: The process of deciding these 2 params is bit complex include a lot of conditional checks and parallel selection of inputs , Thats why planning tokeep its logic as a seprate one and return with result only ie 2 Ids actionid and referenceID. Example First decide liceonsor is new or existing . If decision is existing find existing id , related addressses. Then decide use new address or replace existing address . If decision is to replace existing select the one to replace

Comment: Impossible to give an answer without seeing what your popup is and how you will call it, but in the function the calls it, `$(this)` will be the `<a>` tag, and you can get the associated hidden inputs using `$(this).closest('td').prev('td').children('input');` and then access them using `.eq(0)` and `eq(1)`

Comment: OK That means i have to set the hidden field via JS using Jquery . But is there any solutions like BeginCollection [ obviously cant use here ] available to handle this sort of a case?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

Typically, your view model should be a representation of the page and the elements on the page. If this was to be used on the modal, You could use a partial view template.

You need to create new properties of List to represent the options available for ActionIds and ReferenceIds and pass as parameters for use in the helper functions @Html.DropDownListFor in the view

```
public class VerifyLicensorModel
{
    public int TempId { get; set; } 
    public string Licensor { get; set; } 
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int LicensorId { get; set; }
    public int ActionId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ActionOptions { get; set; }   
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ReferenceOptions { get; set; }   
}
```

On the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActionId, Model.ActionOptions);
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReferenceId, Model.ReferenceOptions);
```

Comment: It is not really 2 related drop downs . Example First decide licencor is new or existing . If decision is existing find existing id [first dropdown], related addresses. Then decide use new address or replace existing address . If decision is to replace existing select the one to replace [second dropdown]. So the decision YES / NO has some impact on building dropdown or filling model